# ActiveRecord NoMethodError when trying to access a has_many collection

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

I have models representing Continent, Country, State, County and City and, for some reason, I'm able to access some collections but not others.

I have these models:

```
class Continent < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :countries
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :continent
  has_many :states
  validates :continent, presence: true
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :counties
  validates :country, presence: true
end

class County < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :cities
  validates :state, presence: true
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :county
  validates :county, presence: true
end
```

My schema is as follows (minus timestamps):

```
 create_table "counties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "state_id", null: false
    t.index ["state_id"], name: "index_counties_on_state_id"
  end

  create_table "continents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "continent_id", null: false
    t.index ["continent_id"], name: "index_countries_on_continent_id"
  end

  create_table "states", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "country_id", null: false
    t.index ["country_id"], name: "index_states_on_country_id"
  end

  create_table "cities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "city_id", null: false
    t.index ["county_id"], name: "index_cities_on_county_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "counties", "states"
  add_foreign_key "countries", "continents"
  add_foreign_key "states", "countries"
  add_foreign_key "cities", "counties"
end
```

---

The following queries work:

`Continent.first.countries` works and returns a collection of countries.
`Continent.first.countries[0].states` works and returns a collection of states.

---

Nothing further works and I'm unable to access any further sub-collections. For example:

`Continent.first.countries[0].states[0].counties`

It returns:

`NoMethodError (undefined method` counties' for #State:0x00007fafc28d4180)`

OR if I use `FIND` to grab a specific county, I still can't access a collection of cities.

For clarification, I have records in the db for all entities.  For example,  the record for California - `#<State id: 331, country_id: 4, created_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32", updated_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32">` and the record for Orange County - `#<County id: 742, name: "Orange County", state_id: 331, created_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32", updated_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32">`. But trying `cali = State.find(331)` yields the California record but `cali.counties` yield `NoMethodError`.

---

What am I overlooking or doing incorrectly?

Why am I able to access some but not others?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run `oc = County.find_by(name: ‘Orange County’)`. Then `oc.state`

Comment: Good question and part of what is perplexing me.  => #<County id: 742, name: "Orange County", state_id: 331, created_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32", updated_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32">
irb(main):008:0> oc.state
  Region Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 331], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<State id: 331, name: "California", country_id: 4, created_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32", updated_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32">
irb(main):009:0>

Comment: It allows me to call the parent state but not the children that are related to the state.  I still get the NoMethodError when going for the children collection.

Comment: What does `Continent.first.countries[0].states[0]` return?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a record in `Continent.first.countries[0].states[0]`, hence you're getting a `NoMethodError (undefined method counties' for #State:0x00007fafc28d4180)` error.

Try inserting a sample record in `State` and do `State.first.counties` if that works.

Comment: Good point.  I should have clarified that I have records for all states and all counties within each state.  For example, here's the record for California - #<State id: 331, country_id: 4, created_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32", updated_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32"> and the record for Orange County - #<County id: 742, name: "Orange County", state_id: 331, created_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32", updated_at: "2020-07-09 19:57:32">.  Still, trying cali = State.find(331) yields the California record but cali.counties yield NoMethodError.

Comment: Hmm, interesting..  In this case I would try a couple things, I would try reloading the console first, then redo your migrations ```rails db:migrate``` and if you have a seed file also try resetting your db just in case.

Comment: Agreed. I’ve done all that you suggested. I’ve reloaded the console and have even dropped the DB, created new dB, reran all migrations and re-seeded. No success.